# Why did I get an Error 401 requesting data in Docker?

Tags: python, docker, curl

I've developed a Python script to be run on Docker.

The script is:

```py
from flask import Flask
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)
api_key = "308b62e9a346baf4145ea2f25ecf480e"
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'App Works!'

@app.route('/&lt;string:city&gt;/')
def weather_by_city(city):
    url=f'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={city}&appid={api_key}'
   
    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        data = response.json()
        temp = (data['main']['temp']-273.15)
    # Round the temperature to two decimal places.
        rounded_temp = round(temp, 2)

        print(f'Temperature: {rounded_temp} Celsius')
        desc = data['weather'][0]['description']

        print(f'Description: {desc}')

    else:
        print('Error fetching weather data')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5000)
```

The DockerFile is:

```sh
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt /app
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /app
EXPOSE 5000
CMD [ "python", "app.py"]
```

And the requirements.txt:

```
certifi==2019.9.11
chardet==3.0.4
Click==7.0
Flask==1.1.1
idna==2.8
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.10.3
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
requests==2.31.0
urllib3==2.0.7
Werkzeug==0.16.0
```

I execute the following commands inside the folder containing the above files:

```sh
sudo docker build -t weather:v1 .
sudo docker run -dit --rm -p 5000:5000 --name weather weather:v1
```

I can confirm the docker is running:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE        COMMAND           CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                                       NAMES
1597682007cb   weather:v1   "python app.py"   5 minutes ago   Up 5 minutes   0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp, :::5000->5000/tcp   weather
```

When I want to request data I use the following command:

```sh
curl http://0.0.0.0:5000/london
```

Receiving this output:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>404 Not Found</title>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.</p>
```

If tried to use the command in python3:

```
>>> import requests
>>> requests.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=london&appid=308b62e9a346baf4145ea2f25ecf480e')
<Response [200]>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Somehow, your route has been HTML encoded.

Instead of

```
@app.route('/&lt;string:city&gt;/')
```

it should be

```
@app.route('/<string:city>/')
```

Comment: Thanks @hans-kilian. ""I got this error: curl http://0.0.0.0:5000/london

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">

<title>Redirecting...</title>

<h1>Redirecting...</h1>

<p>You should be redirected automatically to target URL: <a href="http://0.0.0.0:5000/london/">http://0.0.0.0:5000/london/</a>.  If not click the link"". I don't know where is the problem.

Comment: Try `http://localhost:5000/london/` (with a slash at the end)

Comment: I got this <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">

<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>

<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>

<p>The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.</p>